# Updating a line dynamically using SVG / Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, raphael

What I ultimately want to be able to do is to have a circle follow a path that is updated by a server real time.  Think of it as a target following a line.  I already know how to make a circle follow a path thanks to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyeSf/17/).  But my problems come from how to update the line and course of the circle dynamically as ultimately I want a target to follow data being generated by a server and I am not sure how to do it.

For ease of testing I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTmMz/2/) allowing you to click on the screen to place a point, with the aim of this simulating the server data.  The circle shouldl then move towards each point in turn as you click it.

So how do I update an existing path and make the animation continue seamlessly without affecting previous parts of the path?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle to get you started http://jsfiddle.net/vHRUT/

Comment: Hey @Duopixel thanks, that is a really great example.  How might you change it such that it goes to each point in turn as you add them? Also please put it as an answer :)